# How to print hardcoded array data as comments with reply's?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get my hardcoded array data to print out as comments with reply's. I need to do it in a single component file.

I can get it to print out as a list, but I need it to look like a usual comment.

```js
    comments: [{
      id: 1,
      user_id: 'Lucy',
      content: 'Test Comment',
      time: '15 minutes ago'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      user_id: 'Chuck',
      content: 'Test comment 2',
      time: '20 minutes ago'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      user_id: 'Suzy',
      content: 'Reply comment',
      time: '30 minutes ago'
    }]
```

I've tried using v-for with key binding, but it only comes out as a list or with all the brackets and braces showing.

Comment: What do you mean "a usual comment"? Is there some specific formatting? Also, you've given the data for comments, but not how you've tried to display them. Show some of the markup and it'll be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently showing the raw object that is why there is no formatting.

But you can control how it will look by accessing the object values like this:

`<p{{comment.content}}</p>`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    comments: [{
      id: 1,
      user_id: 'Lucy',
      content: 'Test Comment',
      time: '15 minutes ago'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      user_id: 'Chuck',
      content: 'Test comment 2',
      time: '20 minutes ago'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      user_id: 'Suzy',
      content: 'Reply comment',
      time: '30 minutes ago'
    }]
  }
})
```

```css
.comment_container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.user_id {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.time {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="comment in comments">
    <div :key="comment.id" class="comment_container">
      <p class="user_id">{{comment.user_id}} :</p>
      <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
      <p class="time">{{comment.time}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)